# asp.net checkboxlist text not next to checkbox?

Tags: asp.net, checklistbox

I cannot figure out how to force the asp.net checkListBox  text to be next to (horizontally) the checkboxes ?

Meaning, they text shows up BELOW the checkbox...
There is plenty of room in the width to accomodate the text, why does it drop it down underneath ?

it is defined like so;

```
<asp:CheckBoxList 
ID="CheckBoxList1" 
runat="server" 
Width="665px" 
Font-Size="7pt" 
Font-Bold="False"
CellPadding="1"
CellSpacing="1"
RepeatColumns="1"
RepeatDirection="Vertical"
RepeatLayout="Table"
TextAlign="Right">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I thought TextAlign="Right" should do this...
But I get this instead:

[image: checkbox alignment]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your repeat layout to something other than table, such as flow.  Something funky could be going on with those tables (something in your css, etc).  I like to avoid html tables wherever I can that isn't displaying tabular data.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList 
  ID="CheckBoxList1" 
  runat="server" 
  Width="665px" 
  Font-Size="7pt" 
  Font-Bold="False"
  RepeatDirection="Vertical"
  RepeatLayout="Flow"
  TextAlign="Right">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods I’ve found on other forum pages:
Force a style update by putting the following above the CheckBoxList:

```
<style type="text/css">
    label { display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

Another method worked on one project, and for some reason, not on another – so this may or may not work:
Add to your stylesheet:

```
.checkboxlist_nowrap label
{
    display:inline;
}
```

The add to your checkbox list tag:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ... CssClass="checkboxlist_nowrap" >
```